# Change color of highstock navigator to be identic to first series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highstock chart and will add and remove series one by one as the user selects different checkboxes. Each series has it's own pre-defined color and for each series I will also add a series to the navigator with the same color using code inspired from https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series.

Only the first navigator series is automatically handled by highstock (the rest I handle programmatically) and I'd like to change its color once it is drawn to be identic to the color of the user-selected series. I tried several things but non of them work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezoeetvf/2/

```
myChart.addSeries({
        name : 'AAPL',
        color: "#ff3300",
        data : data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }, true);

// series 1 is the auto-added navigator
console.log(myChart.series[1].name);
// trying set it's color in various ways
myChart.series[1].color = "#ff3300";
myChart.series[1].options.color = "#ff3300";
myChart.series[1].options.lineColor = "#ff3300";
```

How can I have the navigator series to be the same color as the first series, which I am adding dynamically?

Comment: You can use Series.update(): http://jsfiddle.net/ezoeetvf/3/ Does this example meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grzegorz Blachliński comment above did the job. I ended up with

```
myChart.series[1].update({color:"#55FF00" });
```

Thanks.