# HighStock navigator series update color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using multiple series (which also is shown in the navigator) and would like the colors of the series to match, so that the Serie A color in the main-chart is the same as the Serie A color in the navigator.

I saw a possible solution here, but it doesn't seem to work (anymore, atleast): [Change color of highstock navigator to be identic to first series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265877/change-color-of-highstock-navigator-to-be-identic-to-first-series)

It seems like the .update() method can't update the color on a navigator-serie.

```
chart.series[1].update({
    color: 'red'
});
```

It is throwing this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'redraw' of undefined

I have made another example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uhj6r84f/2/

**UPDATE**

Added an example that uses chart.addSeries method. Try and click "Add serie" button, and then "Change navigator serie color" button.

http://jsfiddle.net/uhj6r84f/5/

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
chart.series[0].update({
    color: 'red'
});
```

because there is only one series in your example

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/uhj6r84f/3/)

Also the post you are referring has `addSeries()`, So there are two series and added one is updated using

```
chart.series[1].update({
    color: 'red'
});
```

Comment: No you're missing my point :) . I want to change the color of the navigator-serie. I've just edited the question so it uses the chart.addSeries method :)

Comment: still not clear but check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhj6r84f/6/) which targets series[0] rather than series[3]. By the way i don't know  where series[3] exists

Comment: i think you are taking below line which is inside navigator. navigator lines line colors cannot be changed. series[3] you are referring does not exists . lines which are inside navigator  are replica of chart

Comment: Yes I am talking about the line that is inside the navigator. You say "navigator lines line colors cannot be changed" - do you know why and can you link me to any documentation that states this?

Comment: yes I said .Check [navigator](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator) and there  no where mentioned to change navigator line color.